Dualshock controller gives no input on android build
I want to create a 3D game for android, and move the first person character with a PlayStation 4 default controler (DualShock4). In the unity editor, I can move, look and jump freely how I want, however this does not work on an android build. I connect the controler with bluetooth, and it is correctly connected because I can play other games on my phone with that controller. I can just not control my first person character in my game. I am using new Input system with unity verrsion 2022.3.17f1.
The Input Actions window:

Project Settings:

Player Inspector:


Can you show us how you've implemented your input in code / assets?
